# When to use the character's name and when to use she/he?

Tags: fiction, characters, word-choice, pronouns

This is the first short story where I'm using actual names for the characters. Here is a sample:

> "Sorry for the question," Jun said. "But why don' you have friends?"
>
> **Ling** glanced at him, then opened her Asahi cocktail.
>
> "People are scared of me," **she** replied. "Others are angry."
>
> "Because you like to beat them up?"
>
> **She** shook her head without looking at him.
>
> "Because I don't have a soul,"
>
> **Jun** had been fired from his job as a photographer in a wedding firm
>   and had been unemployed for three months. A friend, a wealthy
>   Christian, of his offered him a job; to accompany her eighteen years
>   old daughter in afternoons and evenings. **He** thought it was an unusual
>   job for a twenty six-years old guy, but he didn't have any good reason
>   to refuse.
>
> **Jun** stared at her as if she were a ghost.
>
> "So I guess you lost it somewhere."
>
> **Ling** shook her head and replied, "I was born without one."
>
> **He** stopped talking for a while and looked around. The sky was getting dark and the street lights of
>   the park started to turn on. He noticed that there were no more people
>   jogging around, or kids in the playground.

I'm not sure when to use the name of the characters and when to use he or she.
(I'm also confused about whether omitting or not the dialogue tags).

Comment: Related: [I'm getting tired of “he said” “she said” in dialogue; how do I get around it?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/im-getting-tired-of-he-said-she-said-in-dialogue-how-do-i-get-around-it)

Comment: Not to derail the question but-- "A friend, a wealthy Christian, of his offered him a job;" -- That's really wrong. Needs rewording.

Comment: Seems to me that the use of pronouns in this example is more or less acceptable.  Minimal confusion and not harsh in the prose.

Comment: +1 for the useful question and beautiful writing. Have you thought about asking someone else to read the text - if they can tell whose speaking then what you have is very good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no rule; it's all by ear. Write it however it seems to work at the time, put it aside for a week and reread it, and then have a friend review it to see if it works.

The goal is that the reader should know exactly who is speaking and/or acting, and when. Do whatever you need to do to make it clear.

Comment: It might be worth noting that using a proper noun also *tends* to add personal, intentional emphasis. A pronoun has the most generic feeling while a proper noun is more forceful/personal and a common noun is intermediate. Even this weak example might hint at the effect: "[He | The janitor | Bob] swept up the shattered bottle."