# What are good dialog writing tips?

Tags: style, dialogue, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should dialog be formatted?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/how-should-dialog-be-formatted)

Writing dialogue has been a challenge. 
From the punctuations to the tags, it all still very confusing for me.
Some stuff I want to know:

- **What are good tags to use?** I've been told "he said" is perfectly fine to use but I shouldn't overuse it. The likes of "he asked" and "he exclaimed" should be avoided.
- **How should I punctuate?**
- **How to break up dialog?** Do I insert action in there somewhere?
- **How to break dialog midsentence?**
- Any other useful tips and tricks

p.s.
Correct this:
"I've come to offer you a gift," he paused and sensing that she wasn't going to say anything, continued "your money and position back."

/*
How do I make this a community wiki?
I'm hoping this can be like a summary of important tips for dialog writing.
*/